# Flutter Navigator remove until

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I have a router stack like `pageA -> pageB -> pageC -> pageD`, and I want to pop to `pageA` from `pageD`.

If use `Navigator.of(context).popUntil`, all page's pop transition will be run, but I just want to run the `pageD` transition because every page's navigator transition is different.

I find `Navigator.removeRouteBelow` and `Navigator.removeRoute`, but I can't get the `Route` instance of `PageB` or `PageC`.

Has there a method like `removeUntil`, or any way to resolve my question? Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious about the results you got. Had you achieved to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pageA()),
                ModalRoute.withName("/Home"),
              );
```

Comment: unfortunately, if use this method, the `pageA` will be a new Widget, the state of old `pageA` will be lost, and the route stack will become  `pageA -> pageA`.